# Mathematical pendulum and $\mathbb C P^n$

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-mechanics, projective-varieties

I am very puzzled by the following remark on p.346 in Arnold's book "Mathematical methods of classical mechanics":

*Another method of construction the same symplectic structure on complex projective space consists of the following. Consider small oscillations of a mathematical pendulum with an $n+1$-dimensional configuration space. We make use of the integral of energy to decrease by 1 the degree of freedom of the system, The phase space obtained after this operation is $\mathbb C P^n$ and the symplectic structure on it agrees with the form $\Omega$ described above by a factor.*

Could anybody clarify what is written here and how to get the projective space from a pendulum?

Comment: Consider on $\mathbb{R}^{2(n+1)}$ the harmonic oscillator Hamiltonian $H(x,\xi) = \frac{1}{2}(|x|^2 + |\xi|^2)$. Its flow on $\mathbb{S}^{2n+1} \cong \{ H(x,\xi) = 1\}$ is periodic and the quotient map is exactly the (complex) Hopf fibration, hence the quotient is $\mathbb{C}P^n$.

Comment: @mcd Wait. You gave a way to obtain CP^n but it has nothing in common with the Arnold writing. He definitely did not mean factorisation by trajectories. There should be factorisation by a first integral.